# How to change theme dinamically in react application

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm trying to change the theme of my react application from light to dark (and viceversa) using a button or a switch button (I will decide it later). The fact is: I'm importing the themes' .css directly from bootswatch (I'm currently using "Minty" as the light theme and I want to use "Darkly" as the dark theme (https://bootswatch.com/)). For now I only found that there is the ThemeProvider component but it needs the theme as a .js file in which you must export what you want (and I can't do it since I only have the .css). I also found a ThemeSwitcher on github (https://github.com/raythree/react-bootstrap-theme-switcher) but it seems it's using bootstrap v3 and I actually need v4. There is also a thread on Reddit that suggests to import them in the public folder and change them (https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/9lzm8g/react_switching_themes_css/) but I don't think it's a good practice. Can anybody help me?

edit: I tried the reddit solution: now it's changing the theme but for an instant I can definitely see some pure html things that I don't like at all.
This is my code

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Tabs from "./Tabs";
import "react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.min.css";
import { Helmet } from "react-helmet"

export const Application = () =>{
    const [theme, setTheme] = useState(true)

    const changeThemeHandler = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        setTheme(!theme)
    }

    return(
        <>
            <button onClick={(event) => changeThemeHandler(event)}>Change Theme</button>
            <Helmet>
                <link rel="stylesheet" href={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/${theme ? 'lightbootstrap.min.css' : 'darkbootstrap.min.css'}`} />
            </Helmet>
            <Tabs />
        </>
    )
}

ReactDOM.render(<Application />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

How can I adjust it in order to have a smooth transition from light to dark theme and viceversa?

Comment: Did you find solution for it ?